# React-Native: image is not showing

Tags: android, image, emulation

I write the given code but the image is not showing the app stop in the building.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxie7.jpg) when I run on the emulator stuck in the building process. I try all things but no response.

````
``` import React from "react";
      import { Image, StyleSheet, View, Dimensions} from "react-native";

       const dimensions = Dimensions.get('window');
       const imageHeight = Math.round(dimensions.width * 9 / 16); //calculate with aspect 
       ratio
      const imageWidth = dimensions.width;

     'function App() {

    return (
           <View>
                <Image
                  style={styles.backgroundImage}
                  source={require('D:\nativeproject\AwesomeProject\images\abl.jpg')}
                  />
               </View>
                );
                   }

               const styles = StyleSheet.create({
                 backgroundImage: {
                height: imageHeight,
                width: imageWidth,
                 zIndex: 1,
                    },
                      });

                  export default App; ```
````

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images). Your image path is probably incorrect.